# SqlMembershipProvider passwordStrengthRegularExpression and whitespace

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

We have a website that uses the default System.Web.Security.SQLMembershipProvider to handle users and their passwords. Today I noticed that whitespace doesnt count as a special character which is a bit strange and got me thinking if other specials are invalid as well? It creates a small bit of a problem as we also have validation regexs to match the password earlier in the chain, and those count the whitespace as a valid special character.

My config looks like this:

```
<add connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" 
  enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
  enablePasswordReset="true" 
  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
  applicationName="Payson 2.0" 
  requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
  passwordFormat="Hashed" 
  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="20" 
  minRequiredPasswordLength="8" 
  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
  passwordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=.{6,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})" 
  passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
  name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

You would think that `.*\W` would match whitespace but it doesnt. If I try to change a password from `abcdefg!1` to `abcdefg 1` it fails and my question is why and if there are other non obvious cases as well?